# cant use first letter uppercase in value

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a select where when i choose the option periodica a div change to display block, the problem is when i want to use the value "Periodica" with uppercase P the js just dont work anymore.

i know i can just send the value periodica but i need to store this value as Periodica

```js
function showDiv(divId, element) {
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == "periodica" ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#hidden_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select required name="tdonacion" class="form-control form-group col-md-12" onchange="showDiv('hidden_div', this)">
  <option value="Puntual">Puntual</option>
  <option value="periodica">Periódica</option>
</select>

<div id="hidden_div">
  <select required name="dperiodica" class="form-control form-group col-md-12">
    <option value="Mensual">Mensual</option>
    <option value="Trimestral">Trimestral</option>
    <option value="Semestral">Semestral</option>
    <option value="Anual">Anual</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), it might help you solve this issue.

Comment: do you have another "Periodica" somewhere in your code?

Comment: what do you mean by "the js just dont work anymore"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

JavaScript:

```js
function showDiv(divId, element){
document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == "Periodica" ? 'block' : 'none';}
```

HTML:

```html
<select required name="tdonacion" class="form-control form-group col-md-12" onchange="showDiv('hidden_div', this)">
    <option value="Puntual">Puntual</option>
    <option value="Periodica">Periódica</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js is case sensitive. You can test `element.value == "Periodica"` or use `toLowerCase()`

```js
if("periodica" == "Periodica"){
  console.log("Js isn't case sensitive")
}else{
  console.log("Js is case sensitive")
}
let text = "Periodica";
if(text.toLowerCase() == "periodica"){
  console.log("works")
}
console.log(text + " didn't change");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toLocaleLowerCase()** method.

my suggestion:

```
function showDiv(divId, element){
 document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value.toLocaleLowerCase() == "periodica" ? 'block' : 'none';}
```

hope it will work for you.